# Why python pandas does not use 3-valued logic?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, logical-operators

I wonder why does python pandas / numpy not implement 3-valued logic (so-called Łukasiewicz's logic) with true, false and NA (like for instance R does). I've read (https://www.oreilly.com/learning/handling-missing-data) that this is to some extent due to the fact that pandas uses much more many basic data types than R for example. However, this is not entirely clear to me why in this case it is unavoidable to have this weird behaviour of logical operations with missing values.

Example.

```
import numpy as np
np.nan and False   # so far so good, we have False
np.nan or False    # again, good, we have nan
False and np.nan   # False, good
False or np.nan    # give nan, so again, it is correct
np.nan and True    # weird, this gives True, while it should give nan
True and np.nan    # nan, so it is correct, but switching order should not affect the result
np.nan or True     # gives nan, which is not correct, should be True
True or np.nan     # True so it is correct, again switching the arguments changes the result
```

So the example shows that something very weird happens in comparisons between `np.nan` and `True` values. So what is going on here?

EDIT.
Thanks for the comments, now I see that `np.nan` is considered a "truthy" value. So can anybody explain what does this mean exactly and what is a rationale behind this approach?

Comment: Pandas 2.0 has a lot of changes, including how nulls are handled for non-float types.

Comment: @aryamccarthy the above won't change with `pandas` 2.0, though. This is basic

Comment: For the record, very few languages make a distinction between true, false and some third "NA" value. Typically, either strong typing means only special constants have boolean meaning, or if many objects have boolean meaning, they all ultimately get treated as truthy or falsy. R having an NA value is unusual; general purpose programming languages almost never have such a value (you can write your own logic to simulate it, but ultimately the language only supports truthy or falsyness).

Comment: Yes, I understand that logical operations in R are quite special in this regard. However, both pandas and numpy are designed to solve similar problems as R, so I wonder why the 3-valued logic has not been built into these two modules? Is it due to some technical constraints or is it a, somehow rational, design decision of the authors?

Comment: @sztal note, you aren't using `pandas` in the above code. All of that is pure python, except you are using an attribute of the numpy module, `np.nan`, but that is the same as `float('nan')`, which is just vanilla Python, so you aren't really even using numpy.

Comment: Ok, I see now. I thought that `nan` is specificaly defined as a part of `numpy` (and then used by `pandas`). Thanks, that makes it more understandable to me.

Comment: pandas 1.0.0 was released in Jan. 2020 and it uses 3-valued-logic with the new pd.NA values https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/user_guide/missing_data.html#logical-operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is numpy behaviour and, at least partially, inherited from python:

```
In [11]: bool(float('nan'))
Out[11]: True

In [12]: bool(np.NaN)
Out[12]: True
```

*(NaN is "truthy".)*

Comment: Note: The truthiness dictates the behavior of `and` and `or`.

Comment: It's not even a part of `numpy` really, since `np.nan` is essentially `float('nan')`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga true!

Answer (score 0):

You wrongly misjudged `or` and `and` statements.

`or` would check if first value is True in form of  `bool(value)` if it's `False` then it takes second value.

`and` on the other hand checks if two of the values are `True` **at the same time** in the form of `bool(value1)` and `bool(value2)`

Comment: So how come `np.nan or True` gives `nan`. If one of the arguments is True then the logical or have to produce True regardless of the second argument. So in this case the results should be True, but it is not. And this proves that `np.nan` is not congruent with the 3-valued logic.

Comment: @sztal it's not. `np.nan` is considered "truthy"

Comment: It seems that in this case python check the first argument, sees that it is `np.nan` and declares (prematurely) that the results is undecidable, but it is very decidable, since on of the arguments is True, so the logical disjunction must be True as well.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for backup, wanted to put that in answer, but wanted to try it first, but lack of python interpreter on mobile phone:)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, what does "truthy" exactly mean? It seems to me that this kind of behaviour may be quite dangerous in some situations.

Comment: @sztal truthy means that when you apply `bool()` function to it, it return `True`

Comment: Truthy values are values that evaluate to `True` when you use `bool(some_value)`. Yes, it can be dangerous if you are unaware an uncareful. For example, though, it is a common idiom to check if a container is not empty doing something like `if my_list: do_something()` or `if my_dict: do_something()` because empty built-in containers are falsey.

Comment: @sztal: Per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations): *"In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are used by control flow statements, the following values are interpreted as false: `False`, `None`, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets). All other values are interpreted as true. User-defined objects can customize their truth value by providing a `__bool__()` method."* Since NaN is numeric, and not 0, it should be truthy.

Comment: And that link also mentions the behavior of `and` and `or`, they don't return `True` or `False` specifically, they just return the last value evaluated (where short-circuiting means some values may not be evaluated at all).