# Why does order matter in Logical and/or operation involving np.NaN in python?

Tags: python, numpy, null, logical-operators

Bool value of np.NaN is True. Then why and/or operation behaves so random in python.

```
bool(np.nan) == True
```

If `True or np.nan` evaluates to `True` then why does `np.nan or True` evaluate to `nan`? And this is completely reverse for and operation:

`True and np.nan` is `nan` while `np.nan and True` is `True`.

Comment: I have trouble understanding your examples and the question itself. Anyway due to operator precedence `x and y == z` is equivalent to `x and (y == z)`. Thus obviously is not the same as `y and x == z`.

Comment: See this SO Post... https://stackoverflow.com/q/43925797/6361531

Comment: In addition to Jacques' explanation, this is called [short circuiting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not). Try `2 or 1/0` for example, this will return `2` because the first operand is Trueish and its value is 2. But if you change the order it will raise a ZeroDivisionError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the way the interpreter evaluates expressions with `and`/`or`:

- `or` expressions:

  If the first operand is `True` or equivalent to `True`, the second operand is not evaluated and the value of the first operand is returned.

  If the first operand is `False` or equivalent to `False`, the second operand is evaluated and returned

  *Examples:*

  > `True or np.nan`: `bool(True)` is `True`, therefore return `True`
  >
  > `np.nan or True`: `bool(np.nan)` is `True`, therefore return `np.nan`
  >
  > `False or np.nan`: `bool(False)` is `False`, therefore return `np.nan`
- `and` expressions:

  If the first operand is `False` or equivalent to `False`, the second operand is not evaluated and the value of the first operand is returned

  If the first operand is `True` or equivalent to `True`, the second operand is evaluated and returned

  *Examples:*

  > `True and np.nan`: `bool(True)` is `True`, therefore return `np.nan`
  >
  > `np.nan and True`: `bool(np.nan)` is `True`, therefore return `True`
  >
  > `False and np.nan`: `bool(False)` is `False`, therefore return `False`

Comment: But why at times np.NaN is replaced with True, while at times it is still np.NaN?

Comment: It is not replaced by `True`: depending on whether the first operand is true-ish or not, the first or second operand is returned.